# help me with this problem, Find all eigenvalues of B and their respective eigenspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $c \in \mathbb R^n$ be a nonzero vector and consider the matrix $B \in \mathbb R
^{n × n} $ defined by

$$ B=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  c_1&c_2&\cdots&c_n\\
  c_1&c_2&\cdots&c_n\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
  c_1&c_2&\cdots&c_n\\
\end{array}
\right]. $$

(a) Determine the rank of B.

(b) Find all eigenvalues of B and their respective eigenspace.

please check if the solution is ok, if there is an error please correct, thanks.

Sol.

a)$\quad$as $c$ is a non-zero vector and all rows of matrix B are equal then a single row is linearly independent so rank(B)= 1.

b) $\quad $by $a)$ we have that the $rank(B) = 1$, then $B$ is singular, therefore $0$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ .

by the rank–nullity theorem we have

$Nu(B)=n-1\quad$ we can write $\quad Nu(B-0I)=n-1$

$\quad \Rightarrow $$0$ is an eigenvalue of B with geometrical multiplicity n-1

$\quad $we can write the matrix B as

$\quad$ $B=uc^T$

where
$$ u=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  1\\
  1\\
  \vdots\\
  1\\
\end{array}
\right],\quad  c^T=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  c_1&c_2&\cdots&c_n
\end{array}
\right]. $$

let $v \in \mathbb R^n$ be the eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue of $0$

$\quad \Rightarrow $ $Bv=0$ $\quad \Rightarrow $ $uc^Tv=0$ $\quad \Rightarrow $  $(c^Tv)u=0 \quad$ if and only if  $\quad c^Tv=0$

then

$V_0=\{v \in \mathbb R^n: c^Tv=0\}\quad$  it is the eigenspace that is ascolated to the eigenvalue $0$

to find the other eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 0 \quad$do

$det(\lambda I-B)=0$ $\quad \Rightarrow $ $det(\lambda I-uc^T)=0\quad$ then

$det(\lambda(I-\lambda^{-1}uc^T))=0$  $\quad \Rightarrow $ $\lambda^n det(I-\lambda^{-1}uc^T)=0$ $\quad ...(1)$

using the following property of determinant $\quad det(I+uv^T)=1+v^Tu\quad$ in $\quad(1)\quad$ we have

$\lambda^n (1-\lambda^{-1}c^Tu)=0 \quad$ if and only if  $\quad \lambda =c^Tu \quad $ since $\lambda \neq 0 \quad$  therefore $\quad u \quad$is the eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda =c^Tu \quad$ since

$\quad $ $Bu=(c^Tu)u$

$V_\lambda=[u]\quad$  it is the eigenspace that is ascolated to the eigenvalue $\lambda =c^Tu \quad$

I would like you to help me with the following question.

that guarantees me that $\lambda =c^Tu \neq 0\quad$?

If you see that there is something missing in the solution or something is wrong, please correct me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If $c^Tu=0$ then the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ has algebraic multiplicity $n$.  But its geometric multiplicity is still $n-1$ and its eigenspace is what you found earlier.  In other words there is no other eigenspace to be found.

An example of such a matrix is
$$\pmatrix{1&2&-3\cr1&2&-3\cr1&2&-3\cr}$$
and if you like you can do the specific calculations to check this.